# access dictionary of list index after if control flow

Tags: python

Say I have a list and a dictionary:

```
d = {'a':[0,1,2,3,4,5],'b':[0,1,2,3,4,5],'label':['love','apple','heart','hi','hello','world']}
l = ['hi','hello','world']
```

The dictionary of lists have the same number of items in the list, I'm looping through the list first and then an inner loop through the key,value pairs of the dictionary. My goal is to access the index of the list `d['a']` and `d['b']` whenever `l` is equal to `d['label']`.

My try is the following:

```
for i in l:
    for k,v in d.items():
        if k == 'label':
            for x in v:
                if x == i:
                    # access d['a'][3] and d['b'][3] but here i'm only printing
                    print(x)
```

So basically whenever `l == d['label']` I want the position(index) of `d['a']` and `d['b']` where this event has occurred.

Comment: Why do you need to loop over `d.items()`? Just loop over `d['label']`'

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for all those loops. Use `index()` to get the index of a string in `d['label']`, then you can use that to access the corresponding elements of `d['a']` and `d['b']`.

```
for word in l:
    try:
        index = d['label'].index(word)
        print(word, d['a'][index], d['b'][index])
    except ValueError:
        print(word, "not found")
```

Comment: why `index!=-1` here ?

Comment: I was confusing it with other languages that return `-1` when something isn't found. I've recoded with an exception handler.

Comment: if `d['label']` has duplicated entries this code would not work.

Comment: That's true. I don't know if that's a consideration in the application.

Comment: yeah I pretty much have duplicated entries in `d['label']`. Sorry to not make an example with this test case.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the items in `l` doesn't matter, then use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
for a, b, label in zip(d['a'], d['b'], d['label']):
    if label in l:
        print(a, b)
```

If you need to iterate over the elements in the order they are in `l`, then I would still use `zip` and then sort the result by the label's location in `l`.